# Masking characters in a Swift string

Tags: swift, string, swift5

Is there a canonical way in Swift 5 to mask out all the characters in one Swift String that are not contained (with an exact match) in a second "masking" string?  Perhaps using map and/or a filter?

e.g. maskString("abcdba", withMask: "ab") -> "abba"

or

maskString("abcdba", withMask: "ab" , replaceWith: "?") -> "ab??ba"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replacingOccurrences` with options:

```
let str = "abcdba"

let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^ab]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

print(result)  //"abba"
```

Or you could define a function like this:

```
func maskString (
    _ str: String,
    withMask mask: String ,
    replaceWith replacement: String = ""
    ) -> String {
    return str
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\(mask)]",
            with: replacement,
            options: .regularExpression)
}
```

And use it like so:

```
maskString("abcdba", withMask: "ab")                    //"abba"
maskString("abcdba", withMask: "ab" , replaceWith: "?") //"ab??ba"
```